# Как задать тип данных ячейки в QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Есть таблица, в которой допустим числа в ячейках уже проставлены. 
Как задать тип данных ячейки `float` вместо стартового `str`, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку получился правильный арифметический ответ, а не просто слияние двух строк?

**test_float.ui:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>476</width>
    <height>267</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>421</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>3</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Ответ</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <property name="text">
      <string>5</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <property name="text">
      <string>10</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="2">
     <property name="text">
      <string>любой текст</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="otvet_Button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>170</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Действие</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>476</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: А в чём сложность обработать данные при получении? Ну или копать в сторону ItemDeligate

Comment: @Denis640Kb Обработать данные в 1-10 ячейках можно, а если таких ячеек 500 то не вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from test_float import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(476, 267)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 321, 61))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        self.otvet_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.otvet_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 111, 51))
        self.otvet_Button.setObjectName("otvet_Button")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 476, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.otvet_Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Действие"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)         
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.otvet_Button)

        self.otvet_Button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)

    def onClicked(self):
        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            _sum = 0
            for column in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount() - 1):
                if self.tableWidget.item(row, column) != None:
                    try:
                        _sum +=  float(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                    except:
                        pass                        
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('{:.2f}'.format(_sum)))    

    def cell_changed(self, row, column):
        _sum = 0
        if column == 0 or  column == 1:
            for column in range(0, 2):
                if self.tableWidget.item(row, column) != None:
                    try:
                        _sum +=  float(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                    except:
                        pass
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('{:.2f}'.format(_sum)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> поправил вопрос. добавил в таблицу текст. вопрос состоит в том чтобы для определенной ячейки сделать тип данных int или float. возможно ли через qt designer в настройках выставить тип данных в ячейке или же поправить сам ui файл вручную?

Вы не четко формулируете постановку задачи. Можно сделать практический все, но в ваше случае самое простое задать номера колонок, которые участвуют в расчетах:

```
self.columnPlus = [0, 2]
```

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from test_float import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(544, 234)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 3, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.otvet_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.otvet_Button.setObjectName("otvet_Button")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.otvet_Button, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 544, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.otvet_Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Действие"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.columnPlus = [0, 2]           # <--- укажите какие колонки будем суммировать

        self.otvet_Button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)

    def onClicked(self):
        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            _sum = 0
            for column in self.columnPlus:
                if self.tableWidget.item(row, column) != None:
                    try:
                        _sum +=  float(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                    except:
                        pass                        
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('{:.2f}'.format(_sum)))    

    def cell_changed(self, row, column):
        _sum = 0
        if column in self.columnPlus:
            for column in self.columnPlus:
                if self.tableWidget.item(row, column) != None:
                    try:
                        _sum +=  float(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                    except:
                        pass
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('{:.2f}'.format(_sum)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**test_float.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>544</width>
    <height>234</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
      <property name="rowCount">
       <number>3</number>
      </property>
      <property name="columnCount">
       <number>5</number>
      </property>
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <row/>
      <row/>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>2</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>3</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>4</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Ответ</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <property name="text">
        <string>5</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <property name="text">
        <string>+</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>10</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="3">
       <property name="text">
        <string>=</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="otvet_Button">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Действие</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>544</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваш пример работает только в том варианте если в таблице нет текста в ячейках

Comment: @ВикторПисаренко о каких ячейках с текстом вы говорите?

Comment: поправил вопрос. добавил в таблицу текст. вопрос состоит в том чтобы для определенной ячейки сделать тип данных int или float. возможно ли через qt designer в настройках выставить тип данных в ячейке или же поправить сам ui файл вручную?

Comment: @ВикторПисаренко я добавил ответ на ваш уточняющий вопрос

Comment: Всетаки меня не оставляет вопрос, можно ли в самом ui файле задать тип данных ячейки затрагивая питона?

Comment: @ВикторПисаренко в  `ui` файле - нет. Дизайн и данные - это разные вещи. 
Данные хранятся в моделях. Вставьте где-нибудь строку 
`print(f'model -> {self.tableWidget.model()}')`,  
чтобы увидеть какую модель вы используете и почитайте что это за зверь.